# How to port Content Types using content porter

Tags: content-porter-2013

I am trying to port content of a Publication which has some Content Types. But during the export I am getting below error

> Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.ImportExportException: Managed link to 'tcm:404-222187-128', in the application data of an item '/webdav/430%20Form%20Web%20CA-EN' (with application id 'SiteEdit'), does not exist.
>      at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.ApplicationDataExporter.ConvertToWebDavUrl(TcmUri itemUri, ApplicationData appData, String webdavUrl)
>      at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.ApplicationDataExporter.AddToDependencies(XmlNode node, ApplicationData appData, PackageItem packageItem)
>      at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.ApplicationDataExporter.SaveAppDataToPackageItem(ApplicationData appData, PackageItem packageItem)
>      at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.Process.<>c__DisplayClass2.b__1(Boolean isRetry)
>      at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.InteractiveErrorHandler.Invoke[T](Func`2 function, LocalizableMessage message, Boolean retryAvailable, Boolean isCritical, UserReply additionalUserReplyOptions)

Answer (score 1):

Application Data does not benefit of dependencies check, so if you got some XPM data using other items for example, like in this case a Page Template, and you remove them from the system it won't stop you. So my guess is that you removed some Page Template that is used in a XPM configuration.

So you should probably check your inline editing configuration in `Settings > Inline Editing > Content Types Mapping > your_publication > your_xpm_page_templates`. And maybe your Content Types configuration in the Publication properties.

Check if there is something you miss there.